# Separate implicit vs. explicit definition of equals/hashCode for Java Record, via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, java-16, java-record

Is it possible to determine (via Reflection) for a Java Record class, if it has an implicit or explicit definition of `equals()` and/or `hashCode(Object)`?

For some reflection-based meta-validation of all classes (and thus, also records) across the codebase, we'd like to separate these cases.

As far as I can see, analyzing a record-class through reflection treats both the implicit and explicit as a "declared" method of the concrete type, so I don't see a way to make that distinction.

Sample code (showing there's a declared method in both cases):

```java
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    analyze(R1.class);
    analyze(R2.class);
  }

  private static void analyze(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
    List<Method> hcMethods = Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredMethods())
        .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("hashCode") && m.getParameterTypes().length == 0)
        .toList();
    System.out.format("Class %s has %s declared hashCode() method(s)\n", clazz.getSimpleName(), hcMethods.size());
  }

  public record R1() { }

  public record R2() {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return obj == this;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to still make this separation, in some other way?

Comment: It's not possible to determine if a Java Record class has an implicit or explicit definition of `equals()` and/or `hashCode(Object)` via reflection because both implementations will be declared methods of the record class at runtime. To make this distinction, you could consider using annotations or naming conventions.

Comment: When you look into the method’s bytecode and see an `invokedynamic` instruction, it’s a strong indicator that the method has been generated by the compiler. But why make this distinction anyway, if you provide your own `equals`/`hashCode` implementations for a `record`, they should obey the same contract.

Comment: @Holger "But why make this distinction anyway" -> We want to have validation on our codebase via reflection, verifying for example that either both or neither of `equals` and `hashCode` is overridden, for each of our classes (as otherwise, it's typically an unintended bug). So our goal is precisely to validate that such overrides don't violate the contract they're supposed to adhere to. However for `record`s it is apparently not possible to do this based on the bytecode, if the distinction of implicit vs. explicit cannot be made (as it can be done, for any other class).

Comment: But, as said, in case of a `record`, a custom `equals` or `hashCode` method should obey the general contract of `record` equality. It follows from there that if an overriding method is well behaving, it is not necessary to override the other method, as the predefined method is adhering to the same contract. In other words, the rule that you should always override both methods is specifically for the case that you are changing the equality rules and have to adapt both methods to the new rules, which is precisely what you shouldn’t do with `record` types at all.

Comment: @Holger Of course records *should* obey their contracts, I don't see how that relates to the question. The whole point here is precisely to detect where that's likely violated (i.e., detect developer mistakes). For example, if s.o. overwrites `equals()` in a record with an array member (to use `Arrays.equals()` as part of defining record-equality) but fails to also overwrite `hashCode()` along - that's quite a clear mistake / contract violation - and I would want to detect this like I can for any other class. But it's apparently not possible via standard reflection (for records specifically).

Comment: See, your own example violates the contract for `record` types, but its (generated) `hashCode` method is not inconsistent with `equals`. This part of the contract is actually easy to test, create a copy of the instance via the accessor methods and canonical constructor and check whether `r1.equals(r2) && r1.hashCode() == r2.hashCode()` is fulfilled. But well, if you assume a careless programmer anyway, you can also assume that they won’t add a `final` modifier, like in your example. So when the method is not `final`, it’s not compiler generated.

Comment: How does my example violate the specific requirements for `record` types in any way (I don't think it would)...? It does violate the general Object `hashCode` contract though, precisely because of the missing, matching `hashCode` override that needs to go along with the customized `equals` (-> just what I'd like to detect). Without that, I can build two record instances that are considered `equal` but have differing `hashCode`s. And then it follows that the (generated) `hashCode`, in this situation, *is* in fact inconsistent with the overridden record `equals`, is it not...?

Comment: Your `record R2()` has no components. Therefore, the (generated) `hashCode()` method always returns the same value. A `hashCode()` method always returning the same value is formally consistent with every `equals` implementation. On the other hand, the contract of `record` requires that the equality is determined only by the values of the components, the object identity *must not* be relevant. In other words, all `R2` instances (having no values) must be equal to each other (that’s why the also have the same hash code). A reference comparison like `obj == this` is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: See [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#:~:text=For%20all%20record,equals(copy).)

Comment: Alright, I see now that we've been talking past each other. My bad - I was talking about the scenario I described in a comment earlier, about a record with overridden `equals` (for an array member) but without a matching `hashCode`. So that's on me, I should've chosen my snippet in the initial question more carefully to begin with. It's still possible to have records with one method overridden (*not* in a broken manner like in my snippet) and the other one not (i.e. a case for my intended verification), but well I got my answer of that not being possible via reflection already (for records).

Comment: As said, the generated methods are always `final` whereas humans tend to omit it. So you can at least check for that. It doesn’t catch the case where a developer did think about adding `final` to the `equals` method but forgot to add a `hashCode` method, but better than nothing. It might also create false positives if both methods have been provided but only one declared `final` but that might be acceptable as it is at least a stylistic mistake which can be fixed. And you can verify the contract itself by creating a copy and check that `r1.equals(r2) && r1.hashCode() == r2.hashCode()`.

Comment: True, checking for a `final` modifier is indeed fully sufficient for my purposes, as you suggest. It feels kind of weird that the generated method is even final, even though it is still possible to redefine it (I do realize that it's not really an override in that case, so no actual inconsistency in that regard - but I wouldn't have thought of checking on the final flag in the first place, obviously). Thanks for pointing this out again - if you care to put it into an answer on this question to accept, go right ahead.